# Test wifi link in monitor mode

Tags: networking, wifi, ip

I'm working on a hobby project based on some scripts running on a pi 3b+ connected to a drone that sends video and telemetry (via wifi or 4g connection) to a ground station.
The system works really well; now I'd like to add to those scripts a wifi link in monitor mode as it happens in projects like [openHD](https://github.com/svpcom/wifibroadcast) or [svpcom/wifibroadcast](https://github.com/svpcom/wifibroadcast). I'd like to test it and I'm curious to see how it works as far as range, speed, stability etc.
I have tried with the hardware that I normally use for my standard wifi connection between the drone and the ground station:

```
sudo iw reg set BO
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo iw dev wlan1 set monitor otherbss
sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
sudo iw dev wlan1 set channel 149 HT40+
sudo ifconfig wlan1 <IP> netmask <MASK>
```

The above commands returns no errors to me, but I can't ping the ip that I've assigned with the "ifconfig" command (and of course I have disabled iptables).

I think that it should be possible to create a virtual NIC (maybe a TUN/TAP device) and then bridge it to my wifi NIC in monitor mode; I should give it a try.

Looking at the [svpcom/wifibroadcstWIKI](https://github.com/svpcom/wifibroadcast), you can see that the encode video streaming below that it is pointed to the localhost ip (host=127.0.0.1 port=5600)

```
raspivid -n  -ex fixedfps -w 960 -h 540 -b 4000000 -fps 30 -vf -hf -t 0 -o - | \
               gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=35 ! udpsink sync=false host=127.0.0.1 port=5600
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed/"normal" mode and monitor modes are mutually exclusive. Monitor mode is a special mode, and I am not aware of hardware allowing both modes to operate at the same time. That is a feature of the hardware, and a limitation that cannot be worked around.

If you need to have IP connectivity, and want to use monitor mode at the same time, you will have to have two WiFi interfaces, or attach to it another small device with a WiFi interface in monitor mode just for monitoring purposes.